# AWS - Stack Update Failed: LambdaFunctionRolePolicy0 cannot be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to update an AWS stack but the update is failing on every attempt with the message "The role policy with name LambdaFunctionRolePolicy0 cannot be found". The only change I'm making in this update is the additon of the aws managed policy AmazonAppStreamReadOnlyAccess to the policies of an existing lambda defined in our cloudformation template (redacted version of this below)

```
LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties: 
        CodeUri: Functions
        MemorySize: TheRightAmount
        Timeout: SomeNumberOfSeconds
        AutoPublishAlias: live
        DeploymentPreference:
            Type: !FindInMap [ DeploymentMap, !Ref DeploymentType, DeploymentPreference ]
        Policies:
   *******  - AmazonAppStreamReadOnlyAccess ******
            - Statement:
                - Sid: policy1
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action: 
                    - prefix: suffix
                  Resource: '*'
            - Statement:
                - Sid: policy2
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action: 
                    - prefix: suffix
                  Resource: '*'
```

The only change with this deployment is the highlighted AmazonAppStreamReadOnlyAccess.

When I take a peek at IAM there is definitely a LambdaFunctionRole, which definitely has the two existing permissions policies so I'm a little stumped (hopefully I'm not just being completely thick)

Thus far I have tried adding the policy in the same format as the other two with a single statement-policy little mapping but that produced the exact same issue.

I also checked other lambdas within our template which have readonlyaccess added in the exact same way and can't find any difference in how this is implemented.

My expectation was that this change shouldn't prohibit me updating the stack, and should give the function sufficient permissions to grab appstream session data.

Would really appreciate any insight anyone would have into this issue.